# Add an object in the deph "level" of an object composition with collections

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm learning java and starting to try to do things in the right way...

I don't know if the Title is right, please advice me if it's not    clear, english is not my mother language.
I have a too large amount of code to post it. So i made this    "simplify" version for evidence my doubt.I think it's more clear. If is not enough clear please    tell me.

- **The context**: I have a object A who have a collections of  B object,
  and B have a collection of C objects, and C... a collection of D. I
  need to put the D object in this "composition"(?) of objects. The object D have the information about in which C object should be put in. every C object is assigned to a B object according his id.
- **The problem**:How to know in A to whish B object pass the D object.
- **The "solution"**: make a method to filter the D object according his id and return the B object id.

This is the scheme of my solution:

```
    public class Test2 {
    public static void test (String args[]){
        A a = new A();
        //... filling the A,B,C data..
        //... done...
        //.. now the cake:
        public String newD = "C=45,D=67,more info...."; // 45 is the C id, 67 is the D id.
        D dude = new D(newD);
        // so i need to put this friend in the C object...
        a.addSomeDude(dude); // looks easy...
    }

}
class A{ // I have 3 B's in my collection = B_1, B_2, B_3. And i can have more...
    private List<B> Blist;
    private String id;
    // blah blah
    public void addSomeDude(D dude){ //... ok, i have some problems... i don't know where to put this dude
        String Bid = SaveTheday.whoGoesWhere(dude.getId()); //oh! you save the day SavetheDay, what a suitable name!
        for(B bDude : Blist)
            if(bDude.getId() ==Bid ){
                bDude.addSomeDude(dude);
            }

    }
    //some things...
}
class B{ // I have some C's in my collections...
    private List<C> Clist;
    private String id;
    //blah blah blah
    public void addSomeDude(D dude){ //... i know where to put this dude, i just get the C id from the dude...
        for(C cGuy : Clist)
            if(dude.getCid() == cGuy.getId()){
                cGuy.addSomeDude(dude);
            }
    }
}
class C{ // I i have some D dudes...
    private List<D> Dlist;
    private String id;
    //yes, more things...
    public void addSomeDude(D dude){
        D objectDude = new D(dude.getCId());
        Dlist.add(objectDude);
    }

}
class D{
    private  String id;
    private String cId;
    //...some things and getters
}
class SaveTheday{
    //...well, maybe i can do the job...
    public static String whoGoesWhere(String id){
        String [] B_1 = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"}; // these are C ids...
        String [] B_2 = {"11","22","33","44","55"};
        String [] B_3 = {"12","45","55","66","77"};
        for( String i : B_1)
            if (i.equals(id))
                return "B_1";
        for( String i : B_2)
            if (i.equals(id))
                return "B_2";
        for( String i : B_3)
            if (i.equals(id))
                return "B_3";
        return null;
    }
}
```

This eventually works, but I'm starting to thinks it's a very not friendly OO principles solution. Why?

1. What if i need to add a new C id? yes, add it to the comparison method, but, what about the "open to expansion, no to modification" principle?
2. And if i need to add a new B, unknown number of B's?
3. Where the hell put the whoGoesWhere method, i think i did a good job encapsulating the comparison (i can change it without affect the others classes) but, where to put it? is in the right place?
4. i feel out there should be a better solution to this problem, more flexible, expansible and maintainable solution.

So, can you guys tell me what I'm missing? there's some pattern what I'm not seeing? 
I hope a expressed myself right, if not, please tell me to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just a general note:

`String [] B_1 = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};`

Don't think hard-coding such instructions in a function-body is a good idea. Would rather declare as private class member. Don't know if Java compiler optimizes such thinks, but a it doesn't make sense creating a new Array each time you call "whoGoesWhere".

I wouldn't use Lists in your case. Maps are lots more effizient if you need to search for specific ids (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Your question:

Yeah, it isn't perfect OO programming. You are violating responsibilities. The only one who should be able to generate the new position of D is D. I would never create a method to generate information about another object.

I would pass id of B for D to A as a method parameter. Something like "public void addSomeDude(D dude, String insertInThisB)".

Best place for "whoGoesWhere" would be in D. Even better: String Id_of_B to the constructor of D.

To add D to A I would create a new method "addToA(A a)" in D. And "addToA" calls "a.addSomeDude(this, ID_of_my_B)".

EDIT:
Your questions 1 and 2 are quite tricky. What happens, if you add an unknown B or C?
And the answer depends on where the new information come from. You could either expand the "whoGoesWhere" to something like a bigger "database" which maps D to paths of D and lets you update these information. 
Or you say: You can only create a D if you give me a B and C id where to add this D.

EDIT2:
I would also pass C-id as parameter of "addSomeDude" of A. And then pass C-id as parameter of "addSomeDude" of B. 
Personally I think this is lots better and more OO than using Getters.